# Weird problem in Wick contraction

Tags: simplewick

I am facing a problem in Wick contraction that totally weird. There are two pieces : `$\langle \wick{\c1 p', \c2 k' \vert \overline{\c2 \psi} \c3 \psi \overline{\c1 \psi} \c4 \psi \vert \c4p, \c3 k} \rangle$`and `$\langle \wick{\c1 p', \c3 k' \vert \overline{\c2 \psi} \c3 \psi \overline{\c1 \psi} \c4 \psi \vert \c4 p, \c2 k} \rangle$`. The first one gives a perfect expression but the second one is giving weird result. Somehow one contraction is missing

[image: Expression for 1st contraction]

[[image: Expression for 2nd contraction2]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{simpler-wick}
\begin{document}
$\langle
\wick{
  \c1{p'},
  \c2{k'} \vert
  \c2{\overline{\psi}}
  \c3{\psi}
  \c1{\overline{\psi}}
  \c4{\psi}
  \vert
  \c4{p},
  \c3{k}
}
\rangle$
and
$\langle
\wick{
  \c1{p'},
  \c3{k'}
  \vert
  \c2{\overline{\psi}}
  \c3{\psi}
  \c1{\overline{\psi}}
  \c4{\psi}
  \vert
  \c4{p},
  \c2{k}
}
\rangle$
\end{document}
```

[image]